# How to connect 2 ultrasonic sensors concurrently using python multiprocessing process?

Tags: python

I'm new to python but i'm working on a project in which i need to connect 3 or more Ultrasonic Sensors concurrently. I read all about threads and multiprocessing ran a couple of examples successfully. I know the code has to be run form the command prompt or the PI2 terminal. However, the multiprocessing code I wrote does not work and I cannot figure out why. Could someone please help me.

```
 from multiprocessing import Process
 from gpiozero import DistanceSensor

 ultrasonic = DistanceSensor(echo=18, trigger=23)
 ultrasonic_B = DistanceSensor(echo=25, trigger=24)
 ultrasonic_C = DistanceSensor(echo=12, trigger=16)

 ultrasonic.max_distance = 1
 ultrasonic_B.max_distance = 1
 ultrasonic_C.max_distance = 1

 def A(name):
    while True:
        ultrasonic.wait_for_in_range()
        print('Distance')

        if ultrasonic.wait_for_out_of_range():
            print('Out of range')

def B(name):
    while True:
        ultrasonic_B.wait_for_in_range()
        print('Distance_B')

        if ultrasonic_B.wait_for_out_in_range():
            print('Out of range_B')

def C(name):
    while True:
        ultrasonic_C.wait_for_in_range()
        print('Distance_B')

        if ultrasonic_C.wait_for_out_in_range():
            print('Out of range_B')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = Process(target=A)
    p1 = Process(target=B)
    p2 = Process(target=C)

    p.start()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

I took your suggestions into consideration and was able to make the first loop work but the other 2 loops give me nothing. Here is the updated code

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor

ultrasonic = DistanceSensor(echo=18, trigger=23)
ultrasonic_B = DistanceSensor(echo=25, trigger=24)
ultrasonic_C = DistanceSensor(echo=12, trigger=16)

ultrasonic.max_distance = 1
ultrasonic_B.max_distance = 1
ultrasonic_C.max_distance = 1

def A():
    while ultrasonic.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Distance')

        if ultrasonic.wait_for_out_of_range():
            print('Out of range')

def B():
    while ultrasonic_B.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Distance_B')

        if ultrasonic_B.wait_for_out_in_range():
            print('Out of range_B')

def C():
    while ultrasonic_C.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Distance_B')

        if ultrasonic_C.wait_for_out_in_range():
            print('Out of range_B')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = Process(target=A)
    p1 = Process(target=B)
    p2 = Process(target=C)

    p.run()
    p1.run()
    p2.run()
```

Result comes form first loop
    Distance
    Out of range
    Distance
    Out of range

OK this is what I have

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor

ultrasonic = DistanceSensor(echo=18, trigger=23)
ultrasonic_B = DistanceSensor(echo=25, trigger=24)
ultrasonic_C = DistanceSensor(echo=12, trigger=16)

ultrasonic.max_distance = 1
ultrasonic_B.max_distance = 1
ultrasonic_C.max_distance = 1

def A():
    while ultrasonic.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Distance')

        if ultrasonic.wait_for_out_of_range():
            print('Out of range')

def B():
    while ultrasonic_B.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Distance_B')

        if ultrasonic_B.wait_for_out_in_range():
            print('Out of range_B')

def C():
    while ultrasonic_C.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Distance_B')

        if ultrasonic_C.wait_for_out_in_range():
            print('Out of range_B')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = Process(target=A)
    p1 = Process(target=B)
    p2 = Process(target=C)

    p.start()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: Which is the error/problem? _The code I wrote does not work_ is very generic

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what you mean with "does not work", so I am taking a few guesses here.

The obvious fail here would be:

> TypeError: A() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Since functions `A`, `B` and `C` all take an argument `name`, and you do not provide it in `Process(target=A)`. It works if you just remove the parameter from the functions, since you are not even using it.

You can also provide the argument in the call like this:

```
p = Process(target=A, args=('ultra_a',))
```

Other one could be indentation error, at least in your code paste you have one extra space at each line until def B.

Comment: Thank you so much Teemu Risikko, I will try to apply your suggestions.

Comment: @Manny No problem, and welcome to Stackoverflow! If an answer resolves your problem, remember to mark it as accepted, so others will benefit from it too!

Comment: Hey I made some changes and was able to get one loop to work but the other 2 loops yield no results. Could you please help me if you can. Thanks

Comment: It does not work because you changed `p.start()` to `p.run()`. Like that it only ever keeps running the first process. Change them back and it should work.

Comment: I just did what you said and nothing happened( no errors, it's just blank). I'm sorry I know this should be easy but I just don't understand why it's not working:(.

Comment: Hmmm. By blank you mean the program keeps running and nothing happens or that it finishes without doing anything?

Comment: I see you also changed it to `while ultrasonic.wait_for_in_range()`. Should that work? What does the function return? If it returns nothing (`None`), it will never even enter the loop.

Comment: Yes, it keeps running and nothing shows. The function is suppose to make the ultrasonic sensor read anything within the set max_distance.

Comment: Could you edit your post to contain the latest code you now have?

Comment: Well, you still have the `while ultrasonic.wait_for_in_range()`. Using it like this you will never even go inside the while-loop, since the wait_for_in_range() returns nothing. So it will be the same as writing `while None:`

Comment: Oh, and the same goes for `if ultrasonic.wait_for_out_of_range():` - the condition of that should never be True, if I have understood the [documentation](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/api_input.html#distance-sensor-hc-sr04) right.The function returns nothing: when it is out of range, it will just return from the method. Without a return value it is the same as writing `if None:`, which is never True.

Comment: I was able to get them all to work, I will post the code shortly! thank you so much for your time and help:)

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocess
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor


def A():

    ultrasonic = DistanceSensor(echo=18, trigger=23)
    ultrasonic.max_distance = 1

    while ultrasonic.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Sensor_1' ultrasonic.distance, 'm')

        if ultrasonic.wait_for_out_of_range():
            print('0')

def B():

    ultrasonic_B = DistanceSensor(echo=25, trigger=24)
    ultrasonic_B.max_distance = 1

    while ultrasonic_B.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Sensor_2', ultrasonic_B.distance, 'm')

        if ultrasonic_B.wait_for_out_in_range():
            print('0')

def C():
    ultrasonic_C = DistanceSensor(echo=12, trigger=16)
    ultrasonic_C.max_distance = 1

    while ultrasonic_C.wait_for_in_range():
        print('Sensor_3',ultrasonic_C.distance, 'm')

        if ultrasonic_C.wait_for_out_in_range():
            print('0')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = multiprocess.Process(target=A)
    p1 = multiprocess.Process(target=B)
    p2 = multiprocess.Process(target=C)

    p.start()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: *Note the gpiozero library is need it!